# repmat and/or transpose into singleton dimensions

Tags: matlab, matrix, transpose

Let's say I have a non-empty vector `z`.

I would like to replicate and shape this vector into a matrix with dimensions `[r, c, length(z)]`.

For example:

```
z = 1:5;
r = 3;
c = 3;
```

I am looking for a function that gives me:

```
ans(:, :, 1) =
    [ 1 1 1 ]
    [ 1 1 1 ]
    [ 1 1 1 ]

ans(:, :, 2) =
    [ 2 2 2 ]
    [ 2 2 2 ]
    [ 2 2 2 ]

...

ans(:, :, 5) =
    [ 5 5 5 ]
    [ 5 5 5 ]
    [ 5 5 5 ]
```

NOTE:
Doing something like

```
tmp = zeros(r,c,length(z));
tmp = repmat(z, 3, 3, 1);
```

doesn't work. Instead it returns a 15x15 matrix as

```
tmp = 
[ 1:5, 1:5, 1:5 ]
[ 1:5, 1:5, 1:5 ]
[ 1:5, 1:5, 1:5 ]
```

which is *not what I want*.

Transposing `z` first doesn't work either.

**The only solution I know** is to initially set `z` to be the 3rd dimension of a vector:

```
z(1,1,:) = 1:5;
```

Is there more efficient way to do this? Or is this the most effective approach?

COROLLARY: Is there a "transpose"-like function that transposes a vector into singleton dimension? That is, if [`transpose()`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/transpose.html) shapes row vectors into column vectors and vice versa, is there a function that shapes a row/column vector into singleton dimensions and back?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think of `permute` as the n-d analogue of transposition. Transpose swaps the first two dimensions, `permute` swaps any dimensions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First [**`permute`**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/permute.html) the vector so that it's a single 3D vector, **then** use `repmat`:

```
z = permute(1:5, [1 3 2]);
r = 3; c = 3;
out = repmat(z, [r c]);
```

We get:

```
>> out

out(:,:,1) =

     1     1     1
     1     1     1
     1     1     1


out(:,:,2) =

     2     2     2
     2     2     2
     2     2     2


out(:,:,3) =

     3     3     3
     3     3     3
     3     3     3


out(:,:,4) =

     4     4     4
     4     4     4
     4     4     4


out(:,:,5) =

     5     5     5
     5     5     5
     5     5     5
```

`permute` works by shuffling the dimensions of the input vector around.  What we're doing here is that we are switching the column values so that they appear in slices of a single 3D vector.  We then replicate this 3D vector for as many rows and as many columns as you want.

If `permute` is confusing, then assuming `z` hasn't been allocated, you can also do this:

```
z(1,1,:) = 1:5;
```

You can then go ahead and use this `z` with the same `repmat` syntax that I talked about before.

Comment: Is `permute` doing what I asked about in the corollary?

Comment: @marcman - Yes.  Use `permute` to transform into a singleton 3D vector, then `ipermute` to undo it.

Comment: @marcman - Assuming you have a 3D matrix - if you want to take the transpose of each slice independently, you can do: `permute(A, [2 1 3])`.  This interchanges the rows and the columns, but leaves the third dimension unchanged.  3D transposing in MATLAB via `transpose() / ' / .'` isn't supported... so `permute` is one way to do it.

Comment: @marcman - Did any of us answer your question? Let us know if you need any further help.

Comment: Yes you both did. Both methods are viable, so I'm torn which to choose.

Comment: @marcman - oh :) Well if I had to choose, it'd be Dan's since he gave you two different methods as opposed to my one.  If you want to go with who answered first, that'd be me.  Whatever criteria you want to use really.

Comment: This one answered the corollary as well

Answer (score 3):

You can generate that using [`ndgrid`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html)

```
z = 1:5;
r = 3;
c = 3;
[~,~,out]=ndgrid(1:r,1:c,z)
```

or using [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) and [`permute`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/permute.html)

```
out = bsxfun(@plus,permute(z,[3,1,2]),zeros(r,c));
```

Comment: Ah, nice way to think about that!